# How can I convert text frequency in a column to number?

Tags: r, text, aggregate, summary

I'm new to R. Would be grateful for any suggestions!

I have data like this

```
Codes     Categories      Code categories

forage    Animal based    Observations
forage    Crop based      Effects  
rain      Animal based    Effects
rain      Crop based      Observations
...       ....            ...
```

I would like to obtain table like this

```
Observations   Categories       Forage    rain
Animal based     1         1
Crop based       1         1

               Categories       Forage    rain

Effects        Animal based     1         1
Crop based       1         1
Thank you
```

I tried aggregate and summary tools, but no it gives this error:

```
aggregate(merged$category, by=list(category=merged$codes), FUN=sum)
Error in FUN(X\[\[i\]\], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Comment: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html?q=count#counts, `sum` only works with numbers

Comment: Take a look at the `table()` function :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `table` function and use the wanted columns to creat a count table. You can use the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(Codes = c("forage", "forage", "rain", "rain"),
                 Categories = c("Animal based", "Crop based", "Animal based", "Crop based"),
                 "Code categories" = c("Observations", "Effects", "Effects", "Observations"))

table(df$Categories, df$Codes)
```

Output:

```
               forage rain
  Animal based      1    1
  Crop based        1    1
```

Second table:

```
table(df$Code.categories, df$Codes)
```

Output:

```
               forage rain
  Effects           1    1
  Observations      1    1
```